# listview FindItemWithText empty or not?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm searching listview item for specified string. If string is found select listviewitem.

```
ListViewItem index = listview1.FindItemWithText(txtSearch.Text);
```

Pretty simple :) but I'm having hard time to figure, I want to know is index variable is populated, I was thinking to check Length property but I cannot find, so once again how to know is index variable is empty or not?

Thanks

Comment: Probably `index != null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FindItemWithText` method returns `null` if list is empty or there is no matching item. So, just check result for null:

```
ListViewItem item = listview1.FindItemWithText(txtSearch.Text);
if (item != null)
{
   // you have match
}
```